# Image not being loaded in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

On my test facebook page's application I am displaying an image which is loading fine on Chrome/Firefox but fails to load on IE9, all I get is 304. I have been browsing around similar IE9 issues but have not found a satisfactory answer for this problem. I also cleared TIFs in IE9 which has removed all the 304s but is changed the status of image file as "(Aborted)". Attached is a screenshot for both Chrome and IE9.

in Chrome-

[image]

in IE9-

[image]

status in IE9-

[image]

Comment: Can you supply the source for the image / page?

Comment: @Rion- here is the image tag - <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="test image" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Try fully qualifying the src tag, <img src='http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif' ... /> (Don't forget to close the tag either, IE can be very fickle about things like syntax.)

Comment: here is another example http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Test-Page/114815475346244?sk=app_1100276076780313

Answer (score 1):

adding "http://" in the img src field displays it fine for me in ie9 on jfiddle...

Comment: I believe you, but when I simply have:  <img src="w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif"; alt="test image" width="100" height="100"> in jFiddle, I get the alt text rather than the image.  (http://jsfiddle.net/aWbWQ/) if I add "http://", i get the smiley.gif (http://jsfiddle.net/aWbWQ/1/).  I am running ie9.

Comment: it runs fine for me in IE9 on jsfiddle as well, but not on my page